# getting next object sized space in memory in C#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management

I have a class class1 and there is a function defined in C++ as:

```
class1 GetNextObject(class1 x) 
{
    return (x + sizeof(x));
}
```

So this gives the next block in memory typecasted as class1. How do I do this in C#? I need to return the next block of space as a class1 type.

Comment: You don't. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am translating that C++ function to C#. Instead of expecting an array of class1 objects as argument, the C++ function just takes a single object and return the next space in memory

Comment: The original already seems quite hackish, even for C++. No way to do this in C#, luckily.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that in `C#`, as you have no any control of a block space occupied by your type. It's move all around the memory space of your machine as `GC` is trying to de-fragment memory space appeared after garbage collection.

And thow, this is not something you meant to do in `C#` language (or any other `CLR` language basically). If you need deep control on memory consumption and/or memory advanced manipulation, stick with `C++`.

> Instead of expecting an array of class1 objects as argument, the C++
>   function just takes a single object and return the next space in
>   memory

This is not something you have to warry about in C#:

- you create, say, List
- add/remove  values.

How memory is managed is not something you know or warry about, and even if yo know it, it's not something that you in control with, and *may* be also a subject to change (depends on Microsoft architects).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do the same thing in C#. The way memory is managed is very different from C++, and you can't expect that the next block of space might be another valid `class1`, nor can you easily even *see* what memory is next.

You might want to use a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).  E.g.

```
LinkedList<class1> myList = new LinkedList<class1>
    (new[] { new class1(1), new class1(2), new class1(3) });
LinkedListNode<class1> myItem = myList.First;
Console.WriteLine(myItem.Next.Value.Id); // 2

public class class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public class1(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

But the more common approach is to just manage a list as a list. So instead of expecting to be able to get to one `class1` object from another `class1` instance, if you want to be able to reference both, you just pass around the array/list/`IList<T>`/etc. that you want to work with.